# Trying to create a 32 bpc NSBitmapImageRep, getting hit with errors

Tags: swift, image-processing, nsbitmapimagerep

I'm trying to create an NSBitmapImageRep object with 32 bits per sample and an alpha channel (128 bits per pixel in total).

My code looks like this:

```
let renderSize = NSSize(width: 640, height: 360)
let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil, pixelsWide: Int(renderSize.width), pixelsHigh: Int(renderSize.height), bitsPerSample: 32, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: false, colorSpaceName: NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace, bytesPerRow: 16 * Int(renderSize.width), bitsPerPixel: 128)
println(bitmapRep) //prints "nil"
println(16 * Int(renderSize.width)) //prints 10240
println()

//So what does a 'valid' 32bpc TIFF file with an alpha channel look like?
let imgFile = NSImage(named: "32grad") //http://i.peterwunder.de/32grad.tif
let imgRep = imgFile?.representations[0] as NSBitmapImageRep
println(imgRep.bitsPerSample) //prints 32
println(imgRep.bitsPerPixel) //prints 128
println(imgRep.samplesPerPixel) //prints 4
println(imgRep.bytesPerRow) //prints 10240
println(imgRep.bytesPerRow / Int(imgFile!.size.width)) //prints 16
```

This appears in the console after executing line 2:

> 2014-12-31 04:49:16.639 PixelTestBed[4413:2775703] Inconsistent set of values to create NSBitmapImageRep

What's going on here? Why can't I manually create an NSBitmapImageRep with the exact same values that TIFF image has?

By the way, I can't upload the image here because imgur would butcher the image's quality. It's a 3,7 MB 32bpc TIFF with an alpha channel, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign 32 bitsPerSample which is out of the range specified in the docs:

**bps**

> The number of bits used to specify one pixel in a single component of
>   the data. All components are assumed to have the same bits per sample.
>   bps should be one of these values: 1, 2, 4, 8, 12, or 16.

[NSBitmapImageRep Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBitmapImageRep/initWithBitmapDataPlanes:pixelsWide:pixelsHigh:bitsPerSample:samplesPerPixel:hasAlpha:isPlanar:colorSpaceName:bitmapFormat:bytesPerRow:bitsPerPixel:)

Comment: Guess I'll have to make do with 16 bits per sample. Boo, Apple.